# Rails table with a where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, each, where-clause

I have an employee NonAvailability model and instead of displaying all the non availabilities in the table with

```
<% @non_availabilities = NonAvailability.all %>
<% @non_availabilities.each do |non_availability| %>
<%= non_availability.employee.full_name %>
<%= non_availability.date %>
<%= non_availability.time %>
<%= non_availability.reason %>
```

I want to only display the nonavailabilities that correlate to a certain employees id.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to retrieve records in rails. For example you can filter `NonAvailability` with `employee_ids` using `where` method

```rb
ids = [1,2,3,4] # ids of employee
NonAvailabilty.where(employee_id: ids)
```

If you want to utilize method chaining, define a `has_many` and `belongs_to` association in your `Employee` and `NonAvailability` model. Assuming that your design have this specifications.

```rb
# employee.rb
class Employee
  has_many :non_availabilities
end

# non_availability.rb
class NonAvailability
  belongs_to :employee
end
```

Then you can retrieve all `non_availabilites` using `employee` object.

```rb
employee = Employee.find_by(id: 1)
employee.non_availabilities
```

For more info visit this Active Record Association [Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: If I have a JS variable that has the id of the employee I would like to use, how would I take that approach?

Comment: You can use ajax request on that specific route.

Comment: You can use nested resources to make your code clean. You can read it here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources